# FindWindowA function does not yield the expected output in dart foreign function interface

Tags: dart, user32, dart-ffi

The following dart code's expected output is the handle to the file explorer window but the output always comes out to be 0 even though the file explorer window does exist!

```
import 'package:ffi/ffi.dart';
import 'dart:ffi';

void main() {
  DynamicLibrary dl = DynamicLibrary.open('user32.dll');
  final func = dl.lookupFunction<
      IntPtr Function(Pointer<Utf16>?, Pointer<Utf16>?),
      int Function(Pointer<Utf16>?, Pointer<Utf16>?)
    >('FindWindowA');

  print(func(nullptr, 'File Explorer'.toNativeUtf16()));
}
```

I have ran the function `FindWindowA` in a c++ program and it has returned the exptected output with the same input values that are `NULL` and `'File Explorer'`.

In dart using `null` throws the error `Invalid argument(s): argument value for ':ffi_param1' is null`; hence the use of `nullptr`

Comment: If you don't want to do the ffi bit yourself, you can get this through the `win32` package: https://pub.dev/documentation/win32/latest/win32/FindWindow.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FindWindowA` does not take pointers to UTF-16 strings. The `A` in `FindWindowA` stands for "ANSI", which is Microsoft's way of indicating that it uses strings with single-byte code units encoded in the system's local encoding. (This is also indicated by [its signature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-findwindowa), which takes `LPCSTR` arguments.)

If you want to pass UTF-16 strings (which in Microsoft Windows are considered "wide strings"), then use [`FindWindowW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-findwindoww).